# Does Valgrind have an API like Purify/Quantify that lets you disable data recording?

Tags: c++, performance, valgrind, purify, quantify

Something like this Purify/Quantify function:
quantify_stop_recording_data()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client program can use [callgrind specific client requests](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.clientrequests) to control the callgrind tool (enable and disable profiling), unfortunately the [memcheck client requests](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs) (for obvious reasons<sup>1</sup>) don't allow the same sort of control.

<sub><sup>1</sup> memory error checking is dependant on having traced the entire memory state up to the current point in time</sub>

Comment: Right, callgrind can do that. Deleting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.

Valgrind works by encapsulating the whole run of the program, it's not pluggable.

It starts recording from the moment it beguns reading the program and only produce the output (for memory leaks) once the program has shut-down.